# How to set Code Runner on vscode to run Java Files correctly?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

so I install Code Runner on Vscode because the main reason was that I wanted to hide the file path from the terminal so It's more clear what my Output is, I have a hard time to read all the output.

And code runner have a few settings that we can change, the settings that I change were the following:

- I change the Executor Map settings for Java and Python as you see below.
  [Java Executor Map Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr0N1.png)
  Btw, the "clear &&" part it's so it hide the file path, so It's more clear and everything
- Also I enabled that Code Runner runs on the terminal instead of the Output path

And with this 2 simple settings applied the output of this code (Remember is Java):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The output is not what I expect it
[Code Runner Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og4Qi.png)

I did the same thing with Python that looks like this:
[Executor Map Settings for Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN5ON.png)

Code that I run:

```
print("Hello World")
print(input("Name "))
```

And the output looks like this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct4Fx.png)

As you can see the file path at start doesn't show

I want the same results but with Java

**If you want furder explanation let me know, I'm not a native english speaker and I hope you could help me and understand me**

Comment: the code you have shown in your question post as text does not contain any such print statements. provide a [mre]. see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want clean output, add the following settings

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

But the **OUTPUT** panel cannot receive user input, as you modified `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,`, you can let *Code Runner* run the script in the terminal. In this case your configuration is fine.

```json
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "java": "clear && cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "python": "clear && python -u $fileName",
    },
```

[image]

Comment: I used bash and for some reason it didnt, work, so I try with powershell and it did work, thanks tho